# FutureProspect Theme How to deactivate the top toggling effect?

Tags: joomla-2.5, templates, javascript

I am using the FutureProspect template on my Joomla website. The only issue what I am facing is the availability of the following effect, which is irritating on the mobile effect:

[image: Issue]

Kindly let me know how I can avoid this menu from the FutureProspect theme of Joomla.

Comment: Could be Future Prospects http://preview.themeforest.net/item/futureprospects-stylish-corporate-joomla-template/full_screen_preview/400149?_ga=2.267212429.201020676.1528826862-1570716003.1528718929 but that doesn't show a menu like this at all

Answer (score 1):

FutureProspect isn't a core or a widely known/standard template or template framework. It's impossible for us to know how it works, what features it has etc, and even more impossible to understand the issue you are having with an effect from the screenshot you posted.

#### Some essential suggestions:

- Usually templates have settings to enable/disable certain features. Have you searched in its admin UI?
- Read the documentation of the template
- Contact the developers/provider of the template
- Share a link to the website for us, with steps to reproduce the issue  so we can introspect the template and maybe give you some additional suggestions on the issue.
- I see in your tags Joomla 2.5. Joomla 2.5 has reached its end of support since long time ago. Is outdated, non-supported and non secure. You should upgrade to Joomla 3 as soon as you can, which apart of the security, comes with a ton of new features and improvements.